# Need help placing divs on top of each other and placing the last one at the bottom

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a page and I want the last div to be at the bottom but the one on top of it (second to the last) to have a vertical scrollbar on resize or when the elements don't fit. Here is a link to my jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/tgz98s6w/) where you can see that the second to the last div overlaps with the last one sometimes and I want to avoid that. 
I tried setting:

```
#windowsStoreBox {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

But it does not seem to work. 
Thank you

```css
/* 
 CSS File for Sharebox
*/


html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
 color: #FFFFFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:auto;
    font: 15px "Segoe UI", "Tahoma";
 border: 0.05em solid #535353;
 cursor: default;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}


/* SCROLLBAR */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #747474;
    opacity: 0.93;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #171717;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #454545;
}   

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #747474;
}   

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #171717;
    background-image: url('../buttons/angle_up.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 10px 6px;
    background-position: center center;
    border: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:active {
    background-color: #A2A2A2;
    background-image: url('../buttons/angle_up_active.svg');
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #171717;
    background-image: url('../buttons/angle_down.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 10px 6px;
    background-position: center center;
    border: none;
    display: block;
}   

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:active {
    background-color: #A2A2A2;
    background-image: url('../buttons/angle_down_active.svg');
}            

/* END SCROLLBAR */

/* TITLEBAR */

.titlebar {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 32px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    cursor: context-menu;
    background-color: #000000;
 color: #CCCCCC;
}

.titlebar.titlebarLight {
 background-color: #E6E6E6;
 color: #2A2A2A;
}

.titlebarDarkBlur {
 background-color: #3B3B3F;
}

.titlebarLightBlur {
 background-color: #CCCCCC;
}


.titlebar.draggable {
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
}

.titlebar-title {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: light;
    margin-left:36px;
    margin-top:8px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    width: 70%;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.titlebarTitleDarkBlur {
 color: #CCCCCC;
}

.titlebarTitleLightBlur {
 color: #838487;
}

.titlebar-controls {
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
}

.titlebar:after,
.titlebar-controls:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.titlebar-minimize,
.titlebar-resize,
.titlebar-close {
    float: left;
    width: 45px;
    height: 31px;
    margin: 1px 1px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 29px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .2s;
}

span.titlebar-icon {
    font-family: "Segoe MDL2 Assets";
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
}

span.titlebar-icon-light {
 color: #000;
}

.titlebar.draggable .titlebar-close {
    -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
}

.titlebar-close:hover {
    background-color: rgba(232, 17, 35, 0.9);
}

/* END TITLEBAR */


/* SHAREBOX */

#shareBox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center;
 padding-bottom: 1em;
 padding-top: 0em;
 height: 60px;
 max-height: 60px;
 overflow: none;
}

#shareBox div {
 padding-bottom: 0.3em;
}

#shareBoxText {
 font-size: 1.05em;
 /* font-weight normal is 400, and bold is 700, so we want something in between */
 font-weight: 600;
}

#shareBoxFileName {
 font-size: 0.87em;
}

#shareBoxSubText {
 color: #A2A2A2;
 font-size: 0.87em;
}

div.shareBoxSeparator {
 padding-top: 0.25em;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.shareBoxSeparator.padded {
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-right: 15px;
}

div.shareBoxSeparator hr {
 height: 1px;
 background-color: #A2A2A2;
 border: none;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* END SHAREBOX */


/* SERVICES BOX */

#servicesBox {
 /* Add scrolling. The window will be of a fixed height */
 position: fixed;
 padding-top: 0.3em;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: none;
 height: calc(100% - (32px + 60px + 33px));
 max-height: calc(100% - (32px + 60px + 33px));
}

#servicesBoxSocial {
 display: inline-flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center; 
 /*flex-direction: row;*/
}

.shareService {
 display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center;
 width: 66px;
 height: 84px;
}

.shareServiceLogoBox {
 background-color: #6A68D6;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 margin-bottom: 0.25em;
 /* Align logos to the center */
 display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center;
}

.shareServiceLogoImage {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
}

.shareServiceDescription {
 font-size: 0.825em;
}

.shareService:hover {
 background-color: #2E2E2E;
}
/* END SERVICES BOX */


/* WINDOWS STORE BOX */

#windowsStoreBox {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center;
 padding: 0.25em 0;
 font-size: 0.81em;
 border-bottom: 0.05em solid #535353;
 height: 32px;
 max-height: 32px;
 overflow: none;
}

#windowsStoreBox:hover {
 color: #A2A2A2;
}

#windowsStoreBox:hover g {
 fill: #A2A2A2;
}

svg.windowsStoreLogo {
 padding: 0 3px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 position: relative;
 top: -2px;
}

/* END WINDOWS STORE BOX */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Share</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/sharebox.css">
    </head>
    <body >
        
        <!-- TITLEBAR -->
        <div id="titlebar" class="titlebar draggable">
                <div id='titlebar-title' class="titlebar-title"></div>
                <div id='titlebar-controls' class="titlebar-controls">
                    <div id='titlebar-close' class="titlebar-close" title='Close'>
                        <span class='titlebar-icon'>&#xE8BB;</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END TITLEBAR -->
  
        
   <!-- DESCRIPTION BOX -->
   <div id='shareBox'>
    <div id='shareBoxText'>Share</div>
    <div id='shareBoxFileName' data-attr-filelocation='static/img/blank.svg'>tutankhamun.jpg</div>
    <div id='shareBoxSubText'>This item will be shared.</div>
   </div>
   <!-- END DESCRIPTION BOX -->
   
   <!--<div class='shareBoxSeparator padded'><hr /></div>-->
   
   
   <!-- SERVICES BOX -->
   <!-- This box allows you to share on facebook, twitter e.t.c -->
   <div id='servicesBox'>
    <!-- Add links to social media services and mail, onenote e.t.c -->
    <div id='servicesBoxSocial'>
     <!-- All services here -->
     <div class='shareService'>
      <div class='shareServiceLogoBox'><img class='shareServiceLogoImage' src='static/shareAppImages/CopyFileLogo.svg' /></div>
      <div class='shareServiceDescription'>Copy file</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='shareService'>
      <div class='shareServiceLogoBox'><img class='shareServiceLogoImage' src='static/shareAppImages/CopyLinkLogo.svg' /></div>
      <div class='shareServiceDescription'>Copy link</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='shareService'>
      <div class='shareServiceLogoBox'><img class='shareServiceLogoImage' src='static/shareAppImages/MailLogo.svg' /></div>
      <div class='shareServiceDescription'>Instagram</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='shareService'>
      <div class='shareServiceLogoBox'><img class='shareServiceLogoImage' src='static/shareAppImages/MailLogo.svg' /></div>
      <div class='shareServiceDescription'>Mail</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='shareService'>
      <div class='shareServiceLogoBox'><img class='shareServiceLogoImage' src='static/shareAppImages/MailLogo.svg' /></div>
      <div class='shareServiceDescription'>Feedback</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='shareService'>
      <div class='shareServiceLogoBox'><img class='shareServiceLogoImage' src='static/shareAppImages/OneNoteLogo.svg' /></div>
      <div class='shareServiceDescription'>OneNote</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='shareService'>
      <div class='shareServiceLogoBox'><img class='shareServiceLogoImage' src='static/shareAppImages/MailLogo.svg' /></div>
      <div class='shareServiceDescription'>Snip & Sketch</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='shareService'>
      <div class='shareServiceLogoBox'><img class='shareServiceLogoImage' src='static/shareAppImages/SkypeLogo.svg' /></div>
      <div class='shareServiceDescription'>Skype</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='shareService'>
      <div class='shareServiceLogoBox'><img class='shareServiceLogoImage' src='static/shareAppImages/FacebookLogo.svg' /></div>
      <div class='shareServiceDescription'>Facebook</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='shareService'>
      <div class='shareServiceLogoBox'><img class='shareServiceLogoImage' src='static/shareAppImages/TwitterLogo.svg' /></div>
      <div class='shareServiceDescription'>Twitter</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='shareService'>
      <div class='shareServiceLogoBox'><img class='shareServiceLogoImage' src='static/shareAppImages/RedditLogo.svg' /></div>
      <div class='shareServiceDescription'>Reddit</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='shareService'>
      <div class='shareServiceLogoBox'><img class='shareServiceLogoImage' src='static/shareAppImages/PinterestLogo.svg' /></div>
      <div class='shareServiceDescription'>Pinterest</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='shareService'>
      <div class='shareServiceLogoBox'><img class='shareServiceLogoImage' src='static/shareAppImages/FacebookMessengerLogo.svg' /></div>
      <div class='shareServiceDescription'>Messenger</div>
     </div>
     
     <div class='shareService'>
      <div class='shareServiceLogoBox'><img class='shareServiceLogoImage' src='static/shareAppImages/WhatsAppLogo.svg' /></div>
      <div class='shareServiceDescription'>WhatsApp</div>
     </div>
     
     
    </div>
   </div>
   <!-- END SERVICES BOX -->
  
  <!--<div class='shareBoxSeparator' style='padding:0;'><hr /></div>-->
  
  
  <!-- WINDOWS STORE BOX -->
  <div id='windowsStoreBox'>
   <p>
   <svg class='windowsStoreLogo' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 210 210" width="18px" height="18px"><g fill="none" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-dasharray="" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-family="none" font-weight="none" font-size="none" text-anchor="none" style="mix-blend-mode: normal"><path d="M0,210v-210h210v210z" fill="none"/><g fill="#ffffff"><g id="surface1"><path d="M90.36255,26.32691c-1.56372,0.10254 -3.15307,0.43579 -4.7168,0.94848l-13.125,4.35791c-8.02368,2.69165 -13.45825,10.25391 -13.45825,18.68774v21.58447l-26.25,3.69141v98.18116l118.125,16.53442l26.25,-8.66455v-113.15186l-26.25,-9.43359l-13.125,1.8457v-8.4082c0,-9.92066 -7.51098,-17.81616 -16.56006,-19.37988c-3.02491,-0.5127 -6.20362,-0.33325 -9.35669,0.71777l-3.74267,1.2561c-3.05054,-4.46045 -7.8186,-7.61352 -13.15063,-8.53638c-1.51245,-0.25634 -3.05054,-0.33325 -4.6399,-0.23071zM91.43921,39.375c3.76831,-0.35888 6.99829,2.48657 6.99829,6.5625v20.48218l-26.25,3.66577v-19.76441c0,-2.84546 1.7688,-5.3064 4.48609,-6.22925l13.125,-4.35791c0.56396,-0.20508 1.1023,-0.30762 1.64063,-0.35889zM117.68921,45.9375c3.76831,-0.33325 6.99829,2.48657 6.99829,6.5625v10.25391l-13.125,1.82007v-16.79077l4.48609,-1.48681c0.56396,-0.20508 1.1023,-0.30762 1.64063,-0.35889zM149.52759,72.49512l14.53491,5.22949v94.43848l-14.32984,4.7168l-103.79516,-14.53491v-75.31494zM124.6875,89.23462l-32.8125,4.61426v24.27612h32.8125zM85.3125,94.74609l-26.25,3.69141v19.6875h26.25zM59.0625,124.6875v19.6875l26.25,3.69141v-23.37891zM91.875,124.6875v24.27612l32.8125,4.61426v-28.89038z"/></g></g></g></svg>
   Get apps in store
   </p>
  </div>
  <!-- END WINDOWS STORE BOX -->
  
  <!-- clearing div -->
  <div id='styleRuleDiv' style='display:none;'></div>
  
    <script src='static/js/sharebox.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I've misunderstood, but you because you are using fix and absolute they are excluded from the normal document flow.

So you can easily restrict the height of `#servicesBox`. to prevent it from touching the bottom.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/16sn87pa/